# Span disappearing on submit

Tags: javascript, validation, styles, html

I have been requested to create a simple form with JavaScript validation code. I have constructed the entire form and all of my validation scripting is working, however I have been asked to display any relevant errors in Span tags next to the appropriate field (as opposed to displaying alerts as I am used to doing).

I have been told to have a span tag next to each element like text input, radio button etc with the appropriate error text previously entered, and then style each span so that they are hidden. When the submit button is pressed, the script is supposed to change the style of the appropriate span to visible in order to display the text. I have written the code for this but the issue I am having is that my Span errors become visible, but almost instantly they disappear back to the hidden state. Is there any particular reason this could be happening?

Here's some of my code.

HTML:

```
< input type="checkbox" name="agree"/> < span id="agreeSpan>Error text< /span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
color:red;
font-size:small;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

And the JavaScript:

```
   function validateAgreement()
    {

    var agreeBox = document.registration.agree;
    var agreeSpan = document.getElementById('agreeSpan');

   if (!agreeBox.checked) {
      agreeSpan.style.visibility = 'visible';
      return false;
    }
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is it possible that I am trying to style 1 specific span and that the styling attribute for the general span tags is overriding this particular one?

Thanks very much and apologies if this is a rookie question! I'm new to JS :)

Comment: Have you made sure that the form doesn't get submitted after the span is made visible?

Comment: Ahh, good point. How would I go about ensuring this? I was under the impression that by placing 'return false;' beneath the code that would prevent further validation and submission

Comment: Well, yes, you have `return false` in this function, which is good, but what does your `onclick` handler look like?

Comment: Currently, onclick for the submission button simple runs "return validateForm();" - validateForm then runs validateAgreement(); and a number of other functions which I have temporarily commented out

Comment: Ahhh! I believe the error lies within the main function that is being called when I submit. It isn't returning false back to the form when it should be, so the problem was not within the function I pasted here. Thanks a lot for the help! Reminding me to check the onclick function is what led me to find that mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the submit happening, returning false there is not enough. It depends how you're calling that function, which I imagine is something like this

```
<form action='blah' onsubmit='return validateAgreement();'>
 ...
</form>
```

Note the return. The on submit handler needs to be returning false, so you need to make sure to return whatever value your function returns. If you just did...

```
<form action='blah' onsubmit='validateAgreement();'>
 ...
</form>
```

then your form will always get submitted.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had actually just noticed the issue before this was posted thanks to a comment above, but you are exactly correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, you have missed out the closing quote around `id`
It should have been `id="agreeSpan"` but you have typed `id="agreeSpan`